# Fatal error: Class 'RulesI18nStringController' not found in entity.i18n.inc on line 31

Tags: 7, rules, entities

My client drupal site stopped working suddenly and gave me this error `Fatal error: Class 'RulesI18nStringController' not found in entity.i18n.inc on line 31` i checked the rules module and entity module and nothing seems to be messing.
I searched for a solution on the internet with no luck.
I have rules 7.x-2.2 and entity 7.x-1.0-rc3 but i can't login to the site so i can't access update.php to update the rules and entity modules to the latest versions "as it may fix this problem".

So can anybody help me find solve this problem?

PS: If you need any additional information about the problem just ask about it in the comments.

Thanks in advance for you all.

Comment: You can use drush to update your site without logging in.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. i will try it and i hope updating will fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `$update_free_access` variable in your settings.php file. Set it to:

```
$update_free_access = TRUE;
```

You will be able to run update.php without login. Don't forget to turn it back to `FALSE` when done - if left `TRUE`, it can open your site to DoS attacks.

Comment: Tried it and updated my modules and the error message is gone thank you for your help

Comment: Glad it worked :)